# extract currency rate from website using wget and awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to exctract currenty rate from website some source:

```
<span id="aq_usdpln#1_c5">3.81990</span>
```

result should be `USD: 3.81`

also get this code but it doesn't work:

```
wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0"|awk -F"[ >]" '/<span id="aq_usdpln#1_c5">/ {printf "%s"}'
```

Can help somebody and paste correct code ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is ever changing, and it will give different source to different location and different UAs.
When I testing it, the source code it returned don't contain id `"aq_usdpln#1_c5"`, but `aq_usdpln_c5` instead, and it don't have quotes around the id.

I think it's better to use `GNU grep` first, change the `regex` a bit more generalize, then feed to `awk`:

```
$ wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0" | grep -oP "span id=.?aq_usdpln(#1)?_c5.?>\K.*?(?=<)"|awk -F. '{printf "USD: %s.%s\n",$1,substr($2,1,2)}'
USD: 3.81
```

The regex `span id=.?aq_usdpln(#1)?_c5.?>\K.*?(?=<)` for grep:
`.?` is for the open quote, it might exists, or not.
`(#1)?` similar, to be compatible if `#1` exists.
`\K` means the regex will match the things before it, but only return the things after it.
`.*?` means match any longer things, but not greddy.
`(?=<)` means the match should end before a `<`, but not contain the `<` itself.

Also I suggest you to add UA in your wget command.

Remove the `\n` in the `"USD: %s.%s\n"` part if you don't want the newline after the result.

And if you need *round* instead of **truncate**, then `awk '{printf "USD: %.2f",$0}'` for the `awk` part.
-- From your example I can see that you want **truncate** since `3.81990` will round to `3.82`, but you may need this option too.

If you don't want the `grep` part, this works too (need GNU awk):

```
wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0" | awk -F'[.>]' '/^span id=.?aq_usdpln(#1)?_c5/{printf "USD: %s.%s\n",$2,substr($3,1,2)}' RS='<'
```

Or this one which does not require GNU awk:

```
wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0" | awk -F. 'sub(/^span id=.?aq_usdpln(#1)?_c5\"?>/,""){printf "USD: %s.%s\n",$1,substr($2,1,2)}' RS='<'
```

Comment: I have up-voted it for neutralizing it and for good answer, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
yor_command | awk -F"[><]" '{printf("USD: %.02f\n",$3)}'
```

Comment: @ChenA., sure, I have made field separator as `>` OR `<` so when you segrigate the line as per these delmiters then you will see 3rd field is the one which you needed. Once I got 3rd field then I am printing its 2 digits after floating point.

Comment: @ChenA., please do let me know if this worked for you?

Comment: Yes, I played around with it. Wasn't familiar with regex patterns as delimiters. +1

Comment: @ChenA., Cool glad that it helped you. You could actually do `your_command |  awk -F"[><]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i,$i}}'` What it will do, it will give you fierld number and its value. So anyone could easily understand which field value is having which field number in a line.

Comment: This will not work as written, e.g. `awk -F'[><]' '{print "NF: ", NF}'` on the file yields `5007` fields. If is affected by every script, font, table, etc..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thank you David for letting know, could you please put an example for better understanding of me, will be grateful to you.

Comment: Sure, I just saved it as a file and then started messing with it, e.g. `wget -q -O the_file "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0"` (which would save it as `the_file`) It ends up being a one line of nasty crammed together jumbled html with javascript inclusions, tables, fonts, etc..

Comment: Fyi: You can `curl -o filename "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0"` to save the source code to a file.

Comment: @Tiw with `wget` you want `-O` (big Oh) not `-o` (that just logs `stderr`)

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty I found with the html (and javascript, etc..) returned by `wget` is that it is some `148506` characters long consisting of `5007` fields when using `-F'[><]'` as the file-separator.

One solution is to loop over each of the fields and locate your `"span id=aq_usdpln_c5"` text and then taking the next field as the float-value, e.g.

```
wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0" | 
awk -F'[><]' '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        if ($i == "span id=aq_usdpln_c5")
            printf "USD: %.2f\n", $(i+1)
}'
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can simply paste the above in a terminal, e.g.

```
$ wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0" |
> awk -F'[><]' '{
>     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
>         if ($i == "span id=aq_usdpln_c5")
>             printf "USD: %.2f\n", $(i+1)
> }'
USD: 3.82
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you were missing a *sed* function call. Sed helps you to parse and transforms text in the shell.

Try this:

```
wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0" | awk -F ">" '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/<\/span\>//' | awk '{ print substr($0,0,4) }'
3.81
```

1. `awk -F ">" '{ print $2 }'` splits the text on the delimiter `>`, and prints the second part
2. `sed 's/<\/span\>//'` substitues the text `/span>` with noting
3. `awk '{ print substr($0,0,4) }'` **substr(s, i [, n])** Return the at most n-character substring of s starting at i.  If n is omitted, use the rest of s.

Comment: Thanks, can you include it to my code ? with wget ?

Comment: Well, just put wget instead of echo. Updated it in my answer.

Comment: ` wget -q -O - "https://stooq.pl/q/?s=usdpln&c=3d&t=l&a=lg&b=0" | awk -F ">" '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/<\/span\>//' | awk '{ print substr($0,0,4) }'`
then i got  `<hea`